# How to submit one commit for review, but preserve multi-commit history locally?

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm used to working with Github with PRs. There I can create a PR with atomic commits for my colleagues to review. I can do this regardless whether the project I'm working on is using a rebase, merge, or squash strategy for PRs.

I've recently started working in a project that uses Gerrit. Here colleagues want to have one commit per issue to review, so the end result in the master branch is the same as when using Github with a squash strategy.

My workflow on Gerrit is such that I use `git commit --amend` to amend any new changes to a commit with the same change id. However, I have a problem with this. When I want to look at my local history to see what changes I did at what stage, I can't. Since all my local commits are squashed. I know that I can see all patch sets on the Gerrit server, but I want to be able to do that locally.

What is a good solution to my problem? Is there a better workflow out there?

Comment: Yeah, don't just do one commit per issue. It doesn't make any sense, Git is meant to let you make many small commits.

Comment: Depends on how strict some of the rules are you said. You can easily have multiple commits with the same change id and let them be reviewed as a group and squash them before merging (I don't know if that last step will require re-approval in gerrit).